# JQuery fade issue on column header using IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, when I .fadeIn() a column (after .hide() or .fadeOut()), the column header loses its border. It appears as though the background color of the header cells is on top of the border.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CM9hD/4/

In IE8...Click 'Fade Out'. Column 3 will fade out. Click 'Fade In'. Column 3 will fade in, but the header border is missing.

Chrome and Firefox does not have this issue.